# Binance API Hmac Signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

please help I don't know what is wrong with my code.
Endpoints that doesn't need signature work fine, so I guess is a problem with how I am getting the signature. I am getting this error:

```
data: { code: -2014, msg: 'API-key format invalid.' } } }
```

API Doc: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

> SIGNED endpoints require an additional parameter, signature, to be
>   sent in the query string or request body. Endpoints use HMAC SHA256
>   signatures. The HMAC SHA256 signature is a keyed HMAC SHA256
>   operation. Use your secretKey as the key and totalParams as the value
>   for the HMAC operation. The signature is not case sensitive.
>   totalParams is defined as the query string concatenated with the
>   request body.

My code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const qs = require('qs');

const binanceConfig = {
  API_KEY: 'XXXXXXX',
  API_SECRET: 'XXXXXX',
  HOST_URL: 'https://api.binance.com',
};

const buildSign = (data, config) => {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', config.API_SECRET).update(data).digest('hex');
};

const privateRequest = async (data, endPoint, type) => {
  const dataQueryString = qs.stringify(data);
  const signature = buildSign(dataQueryString, binanceConfig);
  const requestConfig = {
    method: type,
    url: binanceConfig.HOST_URL + endPoint + '?' + dataQueryString + '&signature=' + signature,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `X-MBX-APIKEY: ${binanceConfig.API_KEY}`,
    },
  };

  try {
    console.log('URL: ', requestConfig.url);
    const response = await axios(requestConfig);
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
};

const data = {
  symbol: 'ARKBTC',
  recvWindow: 20000,
  timestamp: Date.now(),
};

privateRequest(data, '/api/v3/openOrders', 'GET');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting the `headers` object to have a key of `X-MBX-APIKEY` directly:

```
headers: {
  'X-MBX-APIKEY': binanceConfig.API_KEY,
},
```

Comment: But why is that? The other endpoints that require the API Key but doesn't need to be signed work fine using 'Authorization'